# Letting opponent win when game is ended from within the Game Center App

Tags: ios, game-center

I don't understand what happens when I remove a gkTurnBasedMatch from within the Game Center app. Especially I don't understand I can "punish" ending a match before the end (from the Game Center App) by letting the opponent win?

I have this match in my game on my iPad:

```
(lldb) p (void)NSLog(@"%@", gkMatch)
 <GKTurnBasedMatch 0x17ec08d0 - 
 matchID:1c612b05-e7fd-41a2-a238-5b36e1718777 
 bundleID:XXXXXXXXXX
 status:GKTurnBasedMatchStatusOpen
 message:'' 
 creationDate:2015-04-02 18:55:24 +0000
 currentParticipant:
   <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x17eae510 - 
   playerID:G:2035125373 (local player)
   status:Active
   matchOutcome:None
   lastTurnDate:2015-04-02 18:55:25 +0000
   timeoutDate:(null)>
 participants:
   <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x17eae510 - 
   playerID:G:2035125373 (local player)
   status:Active
   matchOutcome:None
   lastTurnDate:2015-04-02 18:55:25 +0000
   timeoutDate:(null)>,
   <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x17ebf2a0 - 
   playerID:G:1092983134
   status:Active
   matchOutcome:None
   lastTurnDate:2015-04-02 18:56:29 +0000
   timeoutDate:(null)>
matchData.length:17373
matchDataMaximumSize:65536
exchanges:(null)>
```

Then I put my game into background, opens the Game Center App and removes the turn from within the Game Center App. Now all match turn data is removed from the Game Center App, and also from my game app on the iPad.

I can still look at my match from the opponents device (an iPhone). There the match looks like this:

```
(lldb) p (void)NSLog(@"%@", gkMatch)
<GKTurnBasedMatch 0x17a88fc0 - 
matchID:1c612b05-e7fd-41a2-a238-5b36e1718777
bundleID:XXXXXXXXXXXX
status:GKTurnBasedMatchStatusOpen
message:''
creationDate:2015-04-02 18:55:24 +0000
currentParticipant:
  <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x17a89010 - 
  playerID:G:2035125373
  status:Active
  matchOutcome:None
  lastTurnDate:2015-04-02 18:55:25 +0000
  timeoutDate:(null)>
participants:
  <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x17a89010 -
  playerID:G:2035125373 
  status:Active
  matchOutcome:None
  lastTurnDate:2015-04-02 18:55:25 +0000 
  timeoutDate:(null)>,
  <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x17a89020 - 
  playerID:G:1092983134 (local player) 
  status:Active 
  matchOutcome:None
  lastTurnDate:2015-04-02 18:56:29 +0000 
  timeoutDate:(null)> 
matchData.length:17373
matchDataMaximumSize:65536
exchanges:(null)>
(lldb)
```

The match is still open. How can I make the opponent win when the current player ends the game from within the Game Center App? It would be great if I just could disable my game in the Game Center App altogether, but I guess that's not possible(?).

Should the playerQuitForMatch method be called in this case? It's not. Don't know if this is a sandbox thing.